# Multiplying each element of a list with each element of another list in Scheme programming

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, multiplication

i am trying to do the following in Scheme:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list1.Add(2);
list1.Add(4);
list1.Add(6);
list1.Add(8);

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < list1.Count; p++)
    {
         list2.Add(list[i] * list1[p]);
    }
}
```

as seen in the code above, I am trying to multiply each element of the first list with every element in the second list. So 1*2, 1*4, 1*6, 1*8, then going to the next element, 2*2,2*4.. etc.

I am having trouble implementing this into Scheme. I tried using the `map` function but this doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you try it with map and how did it not work like you want? If your only problem is that the result was in nested lists, you could just flatten it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start by defining the two input lists, I renamed them since `list` is a built-in procedure in Scheme and is not a good idea to overwrite it):

```
(define l '(1 2 3 4))
(define l1 '(2 4 6 8))
```

I'm assuming that you want your result list to be "flat" - e.g., it doesn't contain lists of elements, only elements (if you're ok with having a list of lists in `l2`, simply delete the call to flatten below). For that, we need to define the `flatten` procedure:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))

(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) empty)
        ((atom? lst) (list lst))
        (else (append (flatten (car lst))
                      (flatten (cdr lst))))))
```

Finally, the problem at hand. It's simple once you understand how to nest two `map` procedures - take a look at the [nested mappings](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3) section in the book [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

```
(define l2
  (flatten
   (map (lambda (i)
          (map (lambda (j)
                 (* i j))
               l1))
        l)))
```

At this point, `l2` contains the expected answer:

```
(2 4 6 8 4 8 12 16 6 12 18 24 8 16 24 32)
```

Answer (score 3):

Óscar has given a very complete answer to this question, but I wanted to add two minor notes:

The Scheme dialect [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) has a nice built-in form called `for*/list` which does exactly this sort of thing:

```
(for*/list ([i '(1 2 3 4)]
            [j '(2 4 6 8)])
  (* i j))
```

Also, instead of using your own or the library's `flatten` function in the nested-maps solution, you could replace the outer `map` with `append-map` from [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append-map). There are plenty of other ways too, of course ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe nobody has given the most straightforward answer: nested uses of `map`:

```
(append-map (lambda (x)
              (map (lambda (y) (* x y))
                   (list 2 4 8 6)))
            (list 1 2 3 4))
```

`append-map` is a simple variant of `map` that assumes that the mapping function returns a list, so it concatenates all the result lists.  This is a library function in most serious Scheme systems (it's in [the SRFI-1 library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)), but here's a simple, incomplete definition (a complete definition would handle multiple argument lists):

```
(define (append-map f xs)
  (concat (map f xs)))

;;;
;;; Turns a list of lists into a list by appending all the top-level sublists.
;;; This is also a common library function.
;;;
(define (concat lists)
  (if (null? lists)
      '()
      (append (car lists)
              (concat (cdr lists)))))
```