# Efficient way to multiply/add/devide each element of a list with each element of another list in Python

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

I want to multiply each element of a list with each element of another list.

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 1, 2]
lst2 = [2, 2, 2]

lst3 = []

for item in lst1:
    for i in lst2:
        rs = i * item
        lst3.append(rs)
```

This would work, but this is very inefficient in large dataset and can take very long to complete loop. Note, the length of both lists can vary here.

I am fine with using non built-in data structures. I checked numpy and there seems to be way called broadcasting in `ndarray`. I am not sure if it is way to go. So far, multiplying array with scalar works as expected.

```
arr = np.arange(3)
arr * 2
```

This returns:

```
array([0, 2, 4])
```

But they way it works with another array is bit different and I can't seem to achieve above.

I guess it must be something straight forward, but I can't seem to find exact solution needed at the moment. Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Btw, there is similar question for Scheme without considering efficiency [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289139/multiplying-each-element-of-a-list-with-each-element-of-another-list-in-scheme-p)

Edit: Thanks for you answers. Multiplication works, see Dval's answer. However, I also need to do addition and possibly division too exactly same way. For that reason, I updated question a bit.

Edit: I can work with numpy array itself, so I don't need to convert list to array and back.

Comment: numpy is great if you can carry out a several of operations on the data. It's quite expensive cpu wise to convert lists to ndarray and back.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to achieve by doing this, try to find a better way to achieve it. NumPy will at best produce a constant-factor speedup and constant-factor space savings. There's usually a better way to go than taking outer products.

Comment: I feel like it's not good advice to say "there's a better way to go than taking outer products" when you have no idea of what the users application is. Sometimes there isn't anything better, because what you want is an outer product.

Comment: @Dval: Outer products have really low information content. They tend to be pretty uninteresting, in the way that a giant list of all coordinates in a rectangle is uninteresting. Unless you're writing a library's outer product function, you generally want to compute some function of the outer product, and you can frequently compute that without going through an explicit outer product. At the very least, a lazy representation can save a ton of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear operations on arrays like this are the meat-n-potatoes of `numpy`.  Once you have defined the arrays, matrix like operations on them are easy, and relatively fast.  That includes outer products and inner (matrix) products, as well as element by element operations.

For example:

```
In [133]: a=np.array([1,2,1,2])
In [134]: b=np.array([2,2,2])
```

A list comprehension version of your double loop:

```
In [135]: [i*j for i in a for j in b]
Out[135]: [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

A numpy product using broadcasting.  Think a `a[:,None]` as turning `a` into a column vector.

```
In [136]: a[:,None]*b
Out[136]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

element by element division also works

```
In [137]: a[:,None]/b
Out[137]: 
array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]])
```

But this gets more useful when combining operations.

There is overhead in converting lists to arrays, so I wouldn't recommend it for small occasional calculations.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is complete answer :)

Comment: There's also [`numpy.ufunc.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), which might sometimes be considered more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy is the way to go, specifically [numpy.outer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html), which returns the product of each element as a matrix. Using .flatten() compresses it into 1d.

```
import numpy
lst1 = numpy.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
lst2 = numpy.array([2, 2, 2])
numpy.outer(lst1, lst2).flatten()
```

To add to updated question, addition seems to work similar way:

```
numpy.add.outer(lst1, lst2).flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you. Clever indeed, will go look into docs. How does it work with other operation like division, addition etc?

Comment: outer is specifically multiplication. numpy, in general, is extremely fast (relative to other python options, not speaking of other languages).

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) - it's a library designed for complex matrix-based arithmetic.

```
import numpy
lst1 = numpy.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
lst2 = numpy.array([2, 2, 2]]
numpy.outer(lst1, lst2)
```

Comment: Yep, that looks _almost_ like what OP wants -- I think the only thing left to do is to flatten it (in the correct order) to get exactly what OP wants.  You can probably accomplish that via `.ravel()` or `.flat` IIRC.